# Equations are not rendered in MathJax

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering, mathjax

Equations are not rendered in MathJax on any of the SE sites. I can only see that the markdown.  Here's a screenshot -

[image: screenshot]

I tried the steps given [here](http://www.incrediblelab.com/fix-err-name-not-resolved/), restarted my computer too. JavaScript is enabled in settings too. I'm using Google Chrome on Windows 7. What is causing MathJax not to load? What can I do to make it right?

I had asked a question regarding the same here but I've since deleted it due to downvotes(and I accept that it was my fault).

Comment: If nothing is working, it's quite possible that the problem is further on down the line with your ISP or CloudFlare's servers, in which case all you can do is wait until their DNS refreshes. There's really not anything we can do to help you with this.

Comment: Do you use any browser extensions that block JavaScript? The site switch to a different CDN for MathJax and you might have to whitelist the new CDN domain.

Comment: @peter I have an extension of tampermonkey which I use to print the answers on SE. But it was working finely about a week ago.

Comment: The change was about a week ago. It's always a good idea to debug by disabling all extensions and reactivating them one by one.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I tried that too.

Comment: Have you tried another browser?

Comment: What shows the "network" tag in your javascript debugger?

Comment: @peter I tried Chrome, Firefox and IE. But nothing didn't work.

Comment: @peterh I don't know what you are talking about. I'm not a computer expert.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis It is probably not a browser problem, and also not an SE problem. It is a problem probably in your local network. Your computer somehow doesn't get the IP address of the site from which the MathJax is downloaded from. If you are at home, restart your router. Alternatively, there are also alternate solutions, they are more tricky, you can also manually insert its ip address into the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file (in windows). Probably it is solved until now.

Comment: @peterh I restarted the router, opened the file hosts using Notepad(run as administrator, like shown here) but something weird in Chinese language showed up. I tried to change the font it won't work.(I don't understand Chinese)

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis There shouldn't be any Chinese, only English, even on non-English Windowses. Probably you have a virus. Trashing the hosts file was only a side-effect of the infection.

Comment: @peterh Thanks, replacing the `hosts` file with text from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/972034/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default) worked. I can now see the equations clearly.

Comment: @peterh Maybe you could write that comment into an answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: Suggested tag [tag:BUG] (Bug)

Comment: Chrome was blocking the flash plugin few months ago, then and javascript. It may be a cause. However now chrome has javascript enabled. Does the problem exists yet?

Comment: Me too sometimes (rarely) have same issue... it shaws unprocessed commands for approx half minute or one minute, and then loads correctly.  Could it be due to slower network condition?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Replacing the hosts file solved the issue. I can now see the equations.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis I don't have that issue. Just sometimes (not always) rarely, it takes more time to load the math-Jax processed portions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably not a browser problem, and also not an SE problem. It is a problem probably in your local network. Your computer somehow doesn't get the IP address of the site from which the MathJax is downloaded from. If you are at home, restart your router. Alternatively, there are also alternate solutions, they are more tricky, you can also manually insert its ip address into the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file` (in windows). Probably it is solved until now.

About the Chinese text in your this file: In this file, there shouldn't be any Chinese, only English, even on non-English Windowses. Probably you have a virus. Trashing the hosts file was only a side-effect of the infection. Alternatively, it is also possible that some file corruption happened on your machine on unknown reasons (typically, sudden poweroff causes it).

---

As you write, replacing the hosts file from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/972034/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default) solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue. In my case, it was because I had [DNSSEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions) enabled in [Pi-hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-hole) and the IP address of `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` (which hosts MathJax) could not be looked up as it got a "BOGUS (RRSIG missing)" status. Reverting DNSSEC to its default disabled state solved the issue and is not a major loss because unfortunately 90% of DNS entries are not signed anyway.